# MySQL: Combining two queries into one row result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

First part of the query:

```
SET @centerLat = '48.531157';
SET @centerLng = '-123.782959';

SELECT user_id, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @centerLat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(@centerLng) ) + sin( radians( @centerLat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM bid_userloc HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Second aspect is taking the `user_id` and grabbing a bunch of information from the USERS table

I'm still learning what JOIN even means and I don't quite understand how it all works best...

Comment: Do you need `distance` field in result-set?

Comment: yeah, I like that there... it's useful

Comment: Do you need INNER or LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
  SELECT user_id, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @centerLat ) )
  * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(@centerLng) )
   + sin( radians( @centerLat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
   AS distance,columnsfromuserstable FROM bid_userloc bid
   inner join users us on bid.user_id=us.user_id 
    HAVING distance < 25
   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
select * from users where user_id in (select user_id from(

SELECT user_id, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @centerLat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(@centerLng) ) + sin( radians( @centerLat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM bid_userloc HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20

));
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant with JOIN -

```
SET @centerLat = '48.531157';
SET @centerLng = '-123.782959';

SELECT
  t1.user_id, t1.lat, t1.lng,
  (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(@centerLat)) * COS(RADIANS(t1.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t1.lng) - RADIANS(@centerLng)) + SIN(RADIANS(@centerLat)) * SIN(RADIANS(t1.lat)))) distance,
  t2.*
FROM
  bid_userloc t1
JOIN users t2
  ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
HAVING
  distance < 25
ORDER BY
  distance
LIMIT
  0, 20;
```